# Why I get an "11db" error in XCode8 (Swift 3) when in Swift 2 there was none?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, swift3

I initially began to learn swift in August (2016) and since the swift 3 update my initial learning project no longer works.

I am running XCode 8.2.1 on MacBook Pro with the Swift 3 programming language.

The program has a button in the `Main.storyboard` which when clicked calls a method in the `ViewController` program.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: UIButton) {
        print(sender)
    }

}
```

Now, I receive the following message in the console "`11db`"

Comment: 11db... you mean lldb, right? That's the debugger. What's the actual error you get, and what line is the debugger pointing to?

Comment: Generally in Swift 3, that method would be `@IBAction func pressButton(_ sender: UIButton) { print(sender) }`. So remove your connection to that `@IBAction` and start again.